# Illegal assignment from Account to String

Tags: apex, trigger, compile-error

I wrote a trigger which attempts to grab the `LastModifiedById` and populate it to another field. When I use `trigger.NewMap` to get the `LastModifiedById`, it
throws this error:

> Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Account to String

This is the line throwing the error:

```
String userIdString = trigger.newmap.get(acc.LastModifiedById);
```

Here's the complete trigger:

```
trigger Test on Account (after insert) 
{
    system.debug('test::'+trigger.new);
    for (account acc:trigger.new)
    {

        account dd = new account(id=acc.id);
        String userIdString = trigger.newmap.get(acc.LastModifiedById);

        dd.Last_Modified_By_End_User__c =userIdString.substring(0, 15);

        update dd;
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: What's the point of this? You don't need a trigger. Don't code if you don't need it. Just use a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
String userIdString = trigger.newmap.get(acc.LastModifiedById);
```

to:

```
String userIdString = trigger.newmap.get(acc.Id).LastModifiedById;
```

The description of error is quite obvious.